# jQuery Flot Chart. How to Deal With jQuery AJAX Scope: Got `$.plot is not a function` On Local Computer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyway, this is the reproduction: https://codepen.io/dhika345/pen/OrPQxM

As you can see, it got `i.css(...) is undefined` on the console. However, when I invoke it in the window, it's working

Thank you

Code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cz49g",
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (dataSuccess) {
    function labelFormatter(label, series) {
    var str1 = label.split(":");
    return "<div style='font-size:8pt; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:white;'>" + str1[0] + "<br/>" + Math.round(series.percent) + "%</div>";
}

var pie_placeholder2 = $("#pie-chart2").css({
  'width': '60%',
  'min-height': '150px'
});
   var pie_data2 = [];
```

Furthermore in repro